# Book about geometric meaning (visual representation) of linear algebra, Laplace, and Fourier Transforms

Tags: linear-algebra, laplace-transform, book-recommendation

Is anyone able to recommend any books that emphasize the geometric meaning or visual representations of linear algebra (eigenvalues, eigenvectors, and determinants in linear algebra), Laplace, and Fourier transforms?

I do not care so much focused on the mathematical rigour or solutions since there are many other books for that, though that's fine if it is too.

The reason being that I tend not to need to explicitly use these very much and unlike physics where there is a physical/visual abstraction that causes it to remain in my head even with infrequent use, the pure math tends to leak out of my brain without something similar.

Something similar to the 3BLue1Brown videos, but in book form (and more in depth when possible):

Eigenvalues: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PFDu9oVAE-g&list=WL&index=2&t=9s

Determinants: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ip3X9LOh2dk&list=WL&index=3&t=15s

Fourier: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=spUNpyF58BY

Laplace: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6MXMDrs6ZmA

I've only barely seen scarce smatterings of visual representations of the Laplace transform in written material elsewhere, and I've never run into anything for linear algebra outside of the videos above.

Answer (score 0):

Try Gibert Strang. Arguably the best books on applied math concepts are out there.

Comment: Interesting suggestion, but I haven't seen anything from him on Laplace or Fourier transforms

Comment: https://math.mit.edu/documents/uploads/publications/2015_04_15_Publications_gs.pdf